# Difference between isArmed,isPressed and isSelected

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

What is the difference between the following methods  :

```java
jButton.getModel().isArmed()
jButton.getModel().isSelected()
jButton.getModel().isPressed()
```

I do not understand what the documentation says for `isArmed` and the rest two have an obvious documentation. But I do not how do they behave differently.

Comment: I've not tried it, but I might be the state before the action performed is triggered

Comment: @MadProgrammer so when `getModel()` returns `model` field, what exactly is `model` I cant seem to find any information on what exactly `model` is.

Comment: nvm. figured it out. Realized I hadnt looked at AbstractButton API. `getModel()` returns a `ButtonModel` object so you can then call those methods. ugh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`isArmed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html#isArmed%28%29) means:

When the user presses the mouse button down on the `JButton` , but hasn't yet released it, the `JButton` is armed. However the armed state does'nt mean that action is going to be triggered for sure , because The user may release the button while the cursor is over the `JButton`, or the user may move the cursor elsewhere and release.Hence `isArmed` returns true if the `JButton` is armed, else it return `false`.

Comment: no (a nitpick might be that the mouse as trigger is one of several possible, f.i. key works similar), just wanted to know where it is from - or if it's not a quote, don't format it as such :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Ok..then how would u like it to format ;) ? .I have formatted the paragraph a little to say it more precisely about `isArmed` instead of when it is `armed`

Comment: @kleopatra Everyone prefer there own way to present .. I prefer this one. ;-). If you feel anything wrong with it just put forward your opinion . I would humbly consider your suggestion with due respect..:)

Comment: @kleopatra: ok then I remove blockquote if it showing wrong message to the OPs ;)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) explains the difference:

> Pressing the mouse on top of a button makes the model both armed and pressed. As long as the mouse remains down, the model remains pressed, even if the mouse moves outside the button. On the contrary, the model is only armed while the mouse remains pressed within the bounds of the button (it can move in or out of the button, but the model is only armed during the portion of time spent within the button).

As for `isSelected`:

> isSelected() - Indicates if the button has been selected. Only needed for certain types of buttons - such as radio buttons and check boxes.